# How can I improve my proof of Stirling's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals, gamma-function, laplace-method

I'm trying to prove Robbin's inequality:
$$
n! \le \sqrt{2 \pi n}(n/e)^n e^{1/(12n)}.
$$
**Step 1**: I start from the integral formulation
\begin{align}
n! = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} dx
&=
(n/e)^n\int_0^\infty (x/n)^n e^{n-x} dx
\\&=
(n/e)^n\int_{-n}^\infty (1+x/n)^n e^{-x} dx
\\&=
(n/e)^n\int_{-n}^\infty \exp[-x + n\log(1+x/n)] dx
\\&=
(n/e)^n n \int_{-1}^\infty \exp[-x n + n\log(1+x)] dx.
\end{align}
**Step 2**: I want to use Laplace's method, so I pull out [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)
$$
\log(1+x)=x - x^2/2 + \frac{2}{(1 + \xi_x)^3}x^3/6,
$$
where $\xi_x \in [-x,x]$. (Here we used $\frac{d^3\log(1+x)}{dx^3}=\frac{2}{(1+x)^3}$.)

**Step 3**: I split the integral into segments: $[-1, 0]$, $[0, L]$ and $[L, \infty)$.
In the first interval I guess I should use $\xi_x=-1$, but actually we know $\log(1+x)\le x - x^2/2$, so we don't really need Taylor's theorem. (Good, since we would have had a zero divisor.)
In the interval $[0,L]$ we set $\xi_x=0$ since $x^3>0$.
Finally in $[L,\infty)$ in use a simple linear bound:
$$\log(1+x) \le \log(1+L) + \frac{x-L}{1+L}$$
since $\log(1+x)$ is a concave function. (We have $f(x) \le f(L) + (x-L)f'(L)$ for any concave function and constant $L$.)

**Step 4**: I now do the integrals:

1. Integral one from $-1$ to $0$:
   \begin{align}
   \int_{-1}^0 \exp[-x n + n\log(1+x)] dx
   &\le \int_{-1}^0 \exp[-nx^2/2] dx
   \end{align}
2. Integral two from $0$ to $L$:
   \begin{align}
   \int_{0}^L \exp[-x n + n\log(1+x)] dx
   &\le \int_{0}^L \exp[-nx^2/2 + nL^3/3] dx
   \\&= e^{nL^3/3} \int_{0}^L \exp[-nx^2/2] dx
   \end{align}
3. Integral from $L$ to $\infty$:
   \begin{align}
   \int_{L}^\infty \exp[-x n + n\log(1+x)] dx
   &\le\int_{L}^\infty \exp[n \log(1+L) - n(1+x)L/(1+L)] dx
   \\&\le(1+L)^n \int_{L}^\infty \exp[- n(1+x)L/(1+L)] dx
   \\&=(1+L)^n e^{-L n} \frac{1+L}{L n}
   \\&\le \exp(-n L^2/2 + n L^3/3) \frac{1+L}{L n}.
   \end{align}

**Step 5**: Combine the integrals.
First combining (1) and (2):
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^0 \exp[-nx^2/2] dx
+e^{nL^3/3} \int_{0}^L \exp[-nx^2/2] dx
&\le e^{nL^3/3} \int_{-1}^L \exp[-nx^2/2] dx
\\&\le e^{nL^3/3} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp[-nx^2/2] dx
\\&= e^{nL^3/3} \sqrt{2\pi/n}.
\end{align}

Then combining (1) and (2) with (3):
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^\infty \exp[-x n + n\log(1+x)] dx
\le e^{nL^3/3}\left(\sqrt{2\pi/n} + \exp(-n L^2/2) \frac{1+L}{L n}\right)
\end{align}

**Step 6**: Choose $L$.

I choose $L=n^{-2/3}$.
Putting it all together we have shown
$$
n! \le (n/e)^n \left(
\sqrt{2\pi n} +  (1+n^{2/3})e^{-n^{1/3}/2}\right) e^{1/(3n)}.
$$

That is nearly the $(n/e)^n \sqrt{2\pi n} e^{1/(12n)}$ bound we wanted, but it is off by a factor $1/4$ in the error exponent, and we have that extra annoying $o(1)$ term added onto $\sqrt{2\pi n}$.

**Question**: How can I improve my proof?
I would like to get the full strength of Robbins's inequality, ideally  with similar methods.
If there are any tricks I can use to make the derivation easier, I'm also very interested.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you take is discussed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Alternative_derivation) and yields $n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n(1+\frac{1}{12n}+o(\frac{1}{n}))$, which is not the desired bound by Robbins. While Laplace's method is very useful, I think that Robbins' bound is too sharp for this approach.

I thought about presenting the proof, which follows the other approach discussed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation). But since the original paper is freely [accessible](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Emarin/une_autre_crypto/articles_et_extraits_livres/Robbin_H.-A_remark_on_Stirling%5C%27s_Formula.pdf) and excellently written, there is no need to repeat the argument. Also, there are tons of additional resources, for example a very thorough discussion can be found [here](https://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/pommeren/MathMisc/Stirling.pdf).

Comment: The "bound" you mention $(1 + \frac{1}{12n} + o(\frac{1}{n}))$ isn't really a bound in the "universal over $n$" sense, but simply an asymptotic expansion. Robbin's original bound (which you link) uses a trapezoid method, which doesn't generalize as well as Laplace's method. In the end I want to master Laplace's method for use in other contexts. Thanks for making me aware of Pommerening's proof. It's well written, though it also doesn't use Laplace.

Comment: Robbins' proof does generalize well in that it is an integral approximation of a sum, which leads to Equation (4) in the paper. Of course, the treatment of $\sum_p\epsilon_p=B+r_n$, the coefficient and the remainder, takes some special care.

Comment: I'm not saying Robbin's method can't be used for other integrals. Just that I'm looking for ways to improve my proof, so I can get better at Laplace's method. Not for an entirely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to redo the computations with as few approximations as possible, and then optimize the constants numerically.

In particular, I took the $e^{-n x^2/2}$ integral from $-1$ to $1$, the $e^{-n x^2/2 + n L^3/3}$ from $0$ to $L$, and I generalized the linear bound in the tail to use an arbitrary constant, $a$.

I then plotted the error, $r_n$, when $n!\approx (n/e)^n \sqrt{2\pi n} e^{r_n}$:

[image: graph]

It seems like, while I'm definitely getting $r_n=o(1)$, even tuning every parameter as much as I can, there's no way to get to $r_n\sim 1/(12n)$, at least for small $n$.

I wrote this update as an answer, since that's what it may be: "There's no way to get Robbin's inequality with Laplace's method."

However, I'm definitely very interested in being told otherwise.